# iPhone: how to support vertical scroll in UIPageControl

Tags: objective-c, iphone

thanks in advance.

I have three UITabelView in a UIPageControl, but I could't scroll the UITableView vertically, can anyone tell me how to support this feature in this scenario? Or mission impossible...

Regards,
xiaojun

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to scroll the table views in that scenario. My guess is that the UIPageControl is not large enough to allow user interaction with the table view. Try turning on the clipsSubviews property of the UIPageControl and see if you can still see the table views. Can you select a row in the table or interact with it in any way?